# Get results in predetermined order

Tags: elasticsearch

Would like for the results to be ordered in a specific order that I choose and not simply ascending or descending.

the location_object_code for road is 2 and for town is 1 and city is 3.

```
GET location_object/_search
{
  "size": 100,
  "sort": [{ 
        "road": {
            "unmapped_type": "long" 
            }
        },
        { "town": {
              "unmapped_type": "long" 
            }
        },
        { "city": {
            "unmapped_type": "long" 
            }
        }
  ],  
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "1 2 3 4",
          "fields": ["*.location_object_code"],
          "operator": "or"
        }
      }
  }
```

I want the results to first return roads then towns and then cities.
I cannot order by location_object_code since the order that i want is 2,1,3

The mapping is the same for all three objects:

```
  {  
   "location_object":{  
      "properties":{  
         "area":{  
            "properties":{  
               "properties":{  
                  "type":"object"
               }
            }
         },
         "description":{  
            "type":"text"
         },
         "location":{  
            "properties":{  
               "properties":{  
                  "type":"object"
               }
            }
         },
         "road_name":{  
            "type":"keyword"
         },
         "location_object_code":{  
            "type":"keyword"
         },
         "location_object_name":{  
            "type":"keyword"
         },
         "synonyms":{  
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{  
               "complete":{  
                  "type":"completion",
                  "analyzer":"simple",
                  "preserve_separators":true,
                  "preserve_position_increments":true,
                  "max_input_length":50
               },
               "keywordstring":{  
                  "type":"keyword"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the mapping of index?

Comment: @NishantSaini I loaded the mapping - Thank you.

Comment: You could try adding boost values according to the required order

Comment: @sramalingam24 I have done that in the past but I want to stay away from playing with the boost.

Comment: Using boost is the solution.